# How can I match multiple children class names easily?

Tags: css

I'm trying to match multiple children class names like `div > div > p.class1`, `div > div > p.class2`, `div > div > p.class3`, and so on.

Is there a shorthand notation for `div > div > p.class1, div > div > p.class2, div > div > p.class3`?

Comment: It is possible to do this    class1, class2, class3{}

Comment: and write property

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, there is no way to iterate through class numbers and style each of them (without using SCSS @for). The easiest way to do it in CSS only is separating each selector with a comma:

```css
div > div > p.class1, div > div > p.class2, div > div > p.class3 {
}
```

Or using JavaScript:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   let element = document.querySelector(`.class${i}`)
   element.style.<yourpropertyhere> = <yourvaluehere>
}
```